# Angular digits only directive still allows some characters to be written

Tags: angular, typescript

While I was researching how to best do the digits only directive on the internet, I found the following result close to my own solution:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnlyDigits]'
})

export class OnlyDigitsDirective {
  private navigationKeys = [
    'Backspace',
    'Delete',
    'Tab',
    'Escape',
    'Enter',
    'Home',
    'End',
    'ArrowLeft',
    'ArrowRight',
    'Clear',
    'Copy',
    'Paste'
  ];

  inputElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.inputElement = el.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      this.navigationKeys.indexOf(e.key) > -1 || // Allow: navigation keys: backspace, delete, arrows etc.
      (e.key === 'a' && e.ctrlKey === true) ||   // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true) ||   // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) ||   // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.key === 'x' && e.ctrlKey === true) ||   // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.key === 'a' && e.metaKey === true) ||   // Allow: Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.key === 'c' && e.metaKey === true) ||   // Allow: Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true) ||   // Allow: Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.key === 'x' && e.metaKey === true)      // Allow: Cmd+X (Mac)
    ) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything.
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress.
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || (e.key < '0' || e.key > '9')) &&
      (e.key < 'numpad 0' || e.key > 'numpad 9')
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pastedInput: string = event.clipboardData!
      .getData('text/plain')
      .replace(/\D/g, ''); // get a digit-only string
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, pastedInput);
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const textData = event.dataTransfer!.getData('text').replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.inputElement.focus();
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, textData);
  }
}
```

But when I press Shift+3 twice in a row, it allows typing '^' character. And sometimes it also writes the '+' character.

How can I fix this problem without changing the directive structure?

Comment: Can you give some more info on how to reproduce? OS and browser? I can't reproduce in Firefox or Chrome (Windows 10) or in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n8ubsq?file=src/app/app.component.html I just hammer on shift and 3 and nothing happens.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton ~ Win10, Chrome. Thanks for reply, I checked your stackBlitz try an it still writes ^ character.

Comment: So how do you do it exactly? Do you press the shift+3 keys at the same time, hold one, alternate etc... I can't do it on my end. Do you have a non-standard keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, I'm using it in my ongoing project works perfectly.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumbersOnly]'
})
export class OnlyNumbersDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() allowMultiLine = false;
  @Input() allowNegative = false;
  @Input() allowDecimal = false;
  @Input() maxLength = 0;
  regex: RegExp;

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validate(event, event.key === 'Enter' ? '\n' : event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event'])
  onPaste(event: Event) {
    const pastedText = ( window as any).clipboardData && ( window as any).clipboardData.getData('Text') // If IE, use window
      || ( event as ClipboardEvent) && ( event as ClipboardEvent).clipboardData.getData('text/plain'); // Non-IE browsers
    this.validate(event, pastedText);
  }

  @HostListener('cut', ['$event'])
  onCut(event: Event) {
    this.validate(event, '');
  }

  validate(event: Event, text: string) {
    const txtInput = this.el.nativeElement;
    const newValue = (txtInput.value.substring(0, txtInput.selectionStart)
      + text + txtInput.value.substring(txtInput.selectionEnd));
    if (!this.regex) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-eval
      this.regex = ( eval('/^'
        + (this.allowNegative ? '-?' : '')
        + (this.allowDecimal ? '((\\d+\\.?)|(\\.?))\\d*' : '\\d*')
        + '$/g') as RegExp);
    }
    const lines = this.allowMultiLine ? newValue.split('\n') : [newValue];
    for (const line of lines) {
      const lineText = line.replace('\r', '');
      if (this.maxLength && lineText.length > this.maxLength || !lineText.match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. It offered more than what I needed. Now I'm trying to derive this directive for letter input only with `@Input() allowSpaceBar = false;` , `@Input() allowSpecialChars = false;` etc.

Comment: ~ here is the letter only directive question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71832270/extending-letters-only-directive-angular

Comment: Glad it helps you 

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't reproduce this, a solid failsafe is to just perform a replace on the value of the input. You just need to change the type of input element to `HTMLInputElement` first. Then add the replace wherever necessary, one, two, or all three of these places:

```js
  inputElement: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.inputElement = el.nativeElement;
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      this.navigationKeys.indexOf(e.key) > -1 || // Allow: navigation keys: backspace, delete, arrows etc.
      (e.key === 'a' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.key === 'c' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.key === 'x' && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.key === 'a' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.key === 'c' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true) || // Allow: Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.key === 'x' && e.metaKey === true) // Allow: Cmd+X (Mac)
    ) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything.
      this.inputElement.value = this.inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress.
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || e.key < '0' || e.key > '9') &&
      (e.key < 'numpad 0' || e.key > 'numpad 9')
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.inputElement.value = this.inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.inputElement.value = this.inputElement.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it gets the same result.